# Deriving equation of parabola from general equation of conic

Tags: conic-sections

We can write general equation of conic as:

$$ \frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-k)^2}{a^2(1-e^2)} = 1$$

Where $a$ is some parameter and $e$ is eccentricity of conic

For e=0, it is a circle:

$$(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = a^2$$

similarly,

$0 < e<1$, is it an ellipse

$ e>1$, it is a hyperbola

Now, I want to derive the equation of parabola from this , where $e=1$, however that leads me to blowing up the expression. So, I isolated the expression for $e$:

$$ \frac{(y-k)^2}{ a^2 - (x-h)^2} = 1-e^2$$

$$ e^2 = 1 - \frac{(y-k)^2}{a^2  - (x-h)^2}$$

If we send $e \to 1$, this equation becomes:

$$(y-k)^2 =0$$

Which is the equation of a straight line... not a parabola. Why is that the equation didn't reduce to parabola?

Comment: Because you are not taking appropriate precautions when taking limits --- your focus and directrix into one another.

Comment: Hmm how would I take such precautions @user10354138

Comment: How do I know the coordinates of that point and line without having the equation of conic simplfiied out to give a curve? @user10354138

Comment: What is general is the relation $PS=e PM$ where S(a,0) and Directrix is $x=-a$. You will get the parabola. In the ellipse $S(ae,0)$ and $x=a/e>0$ when you take $e=1$ the focus comes on directrix. So you cannot get parabola like this.

Comment: Thank you, that helped @ZAhmed

Answer (score 1):

**What's wrong with your method**: The ellipse/hyperbola has focus $(h+ c,k)$ and directrix $x=h+a^2/c$ where $c=\pm ae$.  In the limit $e\to 1$, the foci crashes into the directrix so you end up with the perpendicular to the directrix through the foci.

**To do it properly:** You need to scale $a$ as a function of $e$ to to keep them apart.

**Method 1**:  Fix the distance from vertex to directrix.

Fix the conic to have vertex at $(0,0)$ and the focus should be on the positive $x$-axis.  So set the directrix at $x=-a$ and the focus at $(ae,0)$.  The equation of the conic is
$$
(x-ae)^2+y^2=e^2(x+a)^2
$$
Now let $e\to 1$ and you get
$$
y^2=4ax
$$
the equation of the parabola.

**Method 2**: Fix both the directrix and the focus.
Let the focus be at $(a,0)$ and directrix $x=-a$.  Then the equation of our conic is
$$
(x-a)^2+y^2=e^2(x+a)^2
$$
Let $e\to 1$ gives
$$
y^2=4ax
$$
which isn't surprising.

Comment: Makes sense, but I wanted to make it using the original conci equation I wrote because from that one equation, we can understand all conic properties like focus for hyperbola,ellipse circle etc are given as :ae and directix as -a/e but, I guess the crash can't be avoided :(